# Why does The Doctor use Earth time?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel

Throughout the Doctor Who verse, one thing I have noticed is The Doctor using "Earth Time". When going through time, he will often say the year that the Earth is at, rather some sort of "Central Universe Time". Is there any explanation for this, or is it simply to make things easier for his assistants to understand?

Answer (score 17):

As with all speech, I would assume that the Tardis' [Translation Circuit](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Translation_circuit) maps the year the doctor says to something that we can understand. As the Doctor said it's -

> ... gift of the TARDIS, a telepathic field that gets inside your brain
>   — translates.

*The End of the World*

It would make sense for it to translate it into a number or system that was understandable.

Tho in conversation with his assistant, it would make sense for The Doctor to keep things in "Earth Time" as I imagine having to answer the question "but what year is that really?" would be tedious.

Comment: It makes sense for him to use Earth years for companions and such, but what I'm really wanting to know is, for example, when on an alien planet and he travels forwards "10 years", is he referring to 10 Earth years, or 10 years of *that* planet?

Also connected to this question is: is there an officially recognised timeline for the universe. As time is recognised as a dimension, is there a defined unit of measurement in the Who verse that is constant throughout the galaxies?

Comment: I think the Translation Circuit is where it's at. It's amazing how the TARDIS can even get inside of our heads, eh?

Comment: I think it's deliberately ambiguous so fans can convince themselves the timeline actually makes sense.

Comment: The only people who would set up and enforce an "official" timeline for the universe would be the Time Lords, who (along with the Matrix) are conveniently gone.

Comment: I'm guessing this is one of those questions that hasn't had an official "explanation" yet, although I'm not convinced the Translation Circuit is a full answer..

Comment: @AllFallD0wn: Well, it's **you**, an earthling, watching the Doctor (a non-earthling) talking to other non-earthlings, but you still understand what he says, right? Well, *obviously* there's translation at work... ;-)

Comment: I'm not arguing that, my point is more that when you translate to say, Spanish, you don't translate the time, you continue to say the time as you are currently experiencing it, hence why I said "I'm not convinced [it] is a full answer"

Comment: @AllFallD0wn Yes, but that's only because the Spanish use the same date/time system. There's no difference between the translation and the original data, so to speak. The biggest change would be a time offset, but that's only important when you're trying to coördinate across time zones. On the other hand, what if I was an Arab, and I said I was born in the year 1374? And that's peanuts to space... eh, the date/time ambiguities across planets and time travel.

Comment: There are two translations going on.  Inside the story, the Doctor's references to time are (or at least can be) translated to the listener's history and language.  Ancient Romans would hear dates that use the ancient Roman calendar system, but contemporary companions would hear Gregorian dates.  Then, there's the translation for the audience.  The ancient Roman might hear "two hundred years before Rome" but the audience will (or at least might) hear "around 950 BC".  This is the reason we hear English even when everyone in the room is speaking classical Latin, Cybermanian or Judoon.

Comment: @AllFallD0wn: Try Ethopian, then. Their calender is, to this day, about 7 years and 9 months behind the Gregorian Calendar. For them, it's the year 2008.

Answer (score -4):

The 3rd doctor was sentenced to spend time on Earth and had his TARDIS taken away (forcing him to use a transport called Betty).

So he spent fighting aliens on Earth until he got his Type-40 TARDIS. After all that he has studied Earth and learned many things, including to use Earth-time.